# Unity Android build fails to start on google play deploy

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-developers-console

I've made a small game in unity, I can build and run from unity to my phone which works as expected. When I switch to IL2CCP and ARM64, and deploy to google play console, I am getting crashes in my prelaunch internal tests when app tries to start, with below error. Not sure how to get more info from the report details page or what this error means.

Exception Process: com.Twig.Game, PID: 23714
java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2020.3.30f1 (1fb1bf06830e)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'google/redfin/redfin:11/RQ3A.211001.001/7641976:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'MP1.0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-07-28 08:08:33-0700
pid: 23714, tid: 23745, name: UnityMain  >>> com.Twig.Game<<<
uid: 10274
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x778aa06000
x0  b4000077d9ff8b40  x1  0000000000002ee0  x2  b400007887a0e840  x3  0000000000000000
x4  b400007887a0e840  x5  000000778f189248  x6  b400007867a49b90  x7  b400007887a0e790
x8  000000778a80f000  x9  000000778a80f000  x10 000000778fc80858  x11 000000000000043b
x12 0000000000000a1b  x13 000000778aa03794  x14 000000778a9b379c  x15 000000778a80f000
x16 000000778fc9e030  x17 0000007a8bda7180  x18 0000000057b0a803  x19 b400007867a49b90
x20 000000778fd0a000  x21 0000000000000148  x22 000000778fd0a000  x23 000000778fd0a000
x24 000000778fd0a000  x25 000000778fd0a000  x26 00000000000005dc  x27 000000778aa05114
x28 000000778aa05118  x29 000000778f1892c0
sp  000000778f189200  lr  000000778f3d4fb4  pc  000000778f3d4fe0
backtrace:
#00 pc 0000000000244fe0  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 5d59c4e702f66111697b5da937a6cbafb3d16867)
#01 pc 0000000000249f04  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 5d59c4e702f66111697b5da937a6cbafb3d16867)
#02 pc 0000000000249d90  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 5d59c4e702f66111697b5da937a6cbafb3d16867)
#03 pc 000000000023b4ec  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 5d59c4e702f66111697b5da937a6cbafb3d16867)
#04 pc 000000000021c2c0  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (il2cpp_init+36) (BuildId: 5d59c4e702f66111697b5da937a6cbafb3d16867)
#05 pc 0000000000625c0c  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: f9a2a52bc7b2a020c0575d67c1c07bdae5e41448)
#06 pc 0000000000694498  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: f9a2a52bc7b2a020c0575d67c1c07bdae5e41448)
#07 pc 0000000000695198  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: f9a2a52bc7b2a020c0575d67c1c07bdae5e41448)
#08 pc 00000000006ab4c0  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: f9a2a52bc7b2a020c0575d67c1c07bdae5e41448)
#09 pc 00000000000071fc  /data/app/~~w6aaZYIS4rls8590_iJFbQ==/com.Twig.CritterCatch-56CHKvb8N3wbz8jnZoGGHg==/oat/arm64/base.odex
at libil2cpp
at libil2cpp
at libil2cpp
at libil2cpp
at libil2cpp.il2cpp_init (il2cpp_init:36)
at libunity
at libunity
at libunity
at libunity
at base

Comment: Have you tried building a release version with a release signing key and installing it locally?

Comment: Also: Have you tried disabling obfuscation with proguard (if its even enabled).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already, please upload your generated native symbols to Crashlytics using the [Firebase CLI tool](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) as described in these steps to [Get readable crash reports in the Crashlytics dashboard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=unity).

This will take some of those memory adresses and turn them into your more recognizable callstack.